# Migrated from Hibernate 5.x to 6.2 and many things which were working before are now failing

Tags: hibernate, dynamic, orm, quarkus, instantiation

Need help with issue I am facing since I moved from Hibernate 5.x to 6.2. The code which has been working without any issue before is failing now. Here is an example for the query which is failing.

```
public List<MarketCommodityInfo> getMarketCommodityInfoForCommodities(Double longitude, Double latitude,
            Integer page) {

        return getEntityManager().createQuery(
                "SELECT new org.kisanag.model.mandi.MarketCommodityInfo (mci, earth_distance(ll_to_earth(m.latitude, m.longitude), ll_to_earth(:latitude, :longitude)) / :conversion AS distance) FROM MarketCommodityInfo mci JOIN mci.id.market m JOIN mci.id.commodity c WHERE earth_distance(ll_to_earth(m.latitude, m.longitude),ll_to_earth(:latitude, :longitude)) < :within * :conversion ORDER BY distance, mci.id.arrivalDate, c.name",
                MarketCommodityInfo.class)
                .setParameter("latitude", latitude)
                .setParameter("longitude", longitude)
                .setParameter("within", 200)
                .setParameter("conversion", 1000)
                .setMaxResults(pageSize)
                .setFirstResult(page * pageSize)
                .getResultList();

    }
```

This was failing with error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not determine appropriate instantiation strategy - no matching constructor found and one or more arguments did not define alias for bean-injection
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.instantiation.internal.DynamicInstantiationResultImpl.resolveAssembler(DynamicInstantiationResultImpl.java:197)
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.instantiation.internal.DynamicInstantiationResultImpl.createResultAssembler(DynamicInstantiationResultImpl.java:106)
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.StandardJdbcValuesMapping.resolveAssemblers(StandardJdbcValuesMapping.java:53)
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.ResultsHelper.createRowReader(ResultsHelper.java:78)
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.ResultsHelper.createRowReader(ResultsHelper.java:64)
        at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.doExecuteQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:341)
        at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.executeQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:168)
        at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.list(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:93)
        at org.hibernate.sql.exec.spi.JdbcSelectExecutor.list(JdbcSelectExecutor.java:31)
        at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.lambda$new$0(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:109)
        at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.withCacheableSqmInterpretation(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:302)
        at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.performList(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:243)
        at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.doList(QuerySqmImpl.java:521)
        at org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractSelectionQuery.list(AbstractSelectionQuery.java:367)
        at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.list(QuerySqmImpl.java:1084)
        at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:119)
```

I modified the query and added commodityInfo

```
SELECT new org.kisanag.model.mandi.MarketCommodityInfo (mci AS *commodityInfo*, earth_distance(ll_to_earth(m.latitude, m.longitude), ll_to_earth(:latitude, :longitude)) / :conversion AS distance) FROM MarketCommodityInfo mci JOIN mci.id.market m JOIN mci.id.commodity c WHERE earth_distance(ll_to_earth(m.latitude, m.longitude),ll_to_earth(:latitude, :longitude)) < :within * :conversion ORDER BY distance, mci.id.arrivalDate, c.name
```

and now it failing with following error

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.internal.InstantiationException: Unable to determine dynamic instantiation injection strategy for org.kisanag.model.mandi.MarketCommodityInfo#commodityInfo
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.instantiation.internal.DynamicInstantiationAssemblerInjectionImpl.lambda$new$0(DynamicInstantiationAssemblerInjectionImpl.java:82)
        at org.hibernate.internal.util.beans.BeanInfoHelper.visitBeanInfo(BeanInfoHelper.java:55)
        at org.hibernate.internal.util.beans.BeanInfoHelper.visitBeanInfo(BeanInfoHelper.java:48)
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.instantiation.internal.DynamicInstantiationAssemblerInjectionImpl.<init>(DynamicInstantiationAssemblerInjectionImpl.java:35)
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.instantiation.internal.DynamicInstantiationResultImpl.resolveAssembler(DynamicInstantiationResultImpl.java:208)
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.instantiation.internal.DynamicInstantiationResultImpl.createResultAssembler(DynamicInstantiationResultImpl.java:106)
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.StandardJdbcValuesMapping.resolveAssemblers(StandardJdbcValuesMapping.java:53)
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.ResultsHelper.createRowReader(ResultsHelper.java:78)
        at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.ResultsHelper.createRowReader(ResultsHelper.java:64)
        at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.doExecuteQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:341)
        at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.executeQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:168)
        at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.list(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:93)
        at org.hibernate.sql.exec.spi.JdbcSelectExecutor.list(JdbcSelectExecutor.java:31)
        at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.lambda$new$0(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:109)
        at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.withCacheableSqmInterpretation(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:302)
        at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.performList(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:243)
        at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.doList(QuerySqmImpl.java:521)
        at org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractSelectionQuery.list(AbstractSelectionQuery.java:367)
        at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.list(QuerySqmImpl.java:1084)
        at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:119)
```

Here is my class MarketCommodityInfo

```
import jakarta.persistence.EmbeddedId;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Transient;

@Entity
public class MarketCommodityInfo {

    @EmbeddedId
    public MarketCommodityInfoKey id;

    public Double minPrice;
    public Double modalPrice;
    public Double maxPrice;
    public String unit;

    @Transient
    public Double distance;

    public MarketCommodityInfo() {
    }

    public MarketCommodityInfo(MarketCommodityInfo commodityInfo, Double distance) {
        this.id = commodityInfo.id;
        this.minPrice = commodityInfo.minPrice;
        this.modalPrice = commodityInfo.modalPrice;
        this.maxPrice = commodityInfo.maxPrice;
        this.unit = commodityInfo.unit;
        this.distance = distance;
    }
}
```

and the key

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import jakarta.persistence.Embeddable;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToOne;

@Embeddable
public class MarketCommodityInfoKey implements Serializable {

    public Date arrivalDate;

    @OneToOne
    public Commodity commodity;

    @OneToOne
    public Market market;

    public MarketCommodityInfoKey() {
    }

    public MarketCommodityInfoKey(Date arrivalDate, Commodity commodity, Market market) {
        this.arrivalDate = arrivalDate;
        this.commodity = commodity;
        this.market = market;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MarketCommodityInfoKey [arrivalDate=" + arrivalDate + ", commodity=" + commodity + ", market="
                + market + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((arrivalDate == null) ? 0 : arrivalDate.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((commodity == null) ? 0 : commodity.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((market == null) ? 0 : market.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        MarketCommodityInfoKey other = (MarketCommodityInfoKey) obj;
        if (arrivalDate == null) {
            if (other.arrivalDate != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!arrivalDate.equals(other.arrivalDate))
            return false;
        if (commodity == null) {
            if (other.commodity != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!commodity.equals(other.commodity))
            return false;
        if (market == null) {
            if (other.market != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!market.equals(other.market))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

Please help.

Comment: It might be to do with the `earth_distance()` and `ll_to_earth()` functions. Did you register them with Hibernate, so it knows what their return types are?

Comment: No the error specifically says for org.kisanag.model.mandi.MarketCommodityInfo#commodityInfo. Both are Postgres functions and output has a alias distance which it should map to distance field in constructor of MarketCommodityInfo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### UPDATE

My previous answer was incorrect.

The real reason is:

1. Your first attempt (with constructor injection) does not work because Hibernate is not able to determine the return type of the `earth_distance()` function, since you have not registered it as a known SQL function. Hibernate 6 currently insists on knowing the types of all constructor arguments.
2. Your second attempt (with field injection) does not work either, since you have no field named `commodityInfo`. But even if you fix that, it *still* won't work, because Hibernate *still* won't know the type of the `earth_distance()` function.

So the solution is to use a `FunctionContributor` to register this SQL function and its return type.

Now, I suspect that `DynamicInstantiationAssemblerInjectionImpl` is being a bit too fussy here, and that we could improve it to handle your case where not every argument type is known. So I will open an issue about that.

Comment: Why do you think it is has three parameters.  (mci AS commodityInfo, (earth_distance(ll_to_earth(m.latitude, m.longitude), ll_to_earth(:latitude, :longitude)) / :conversion) AS distance). It has only two. Just an FYI it is working perfectly fine with Hibernate 5.x.

Comment: Sorry, I misread. See updated answer.

Comment: Hey Gavin, thanks for taking a look. I will try FunctionContributor for distance but wanted to clarify that regarding commodityInfo, I have the constructor with the same parameter name. --> public MarketCommodityInfo(MarketCommodityInfo commodityInfo, Double distance). Why does it then complain about in the second error.  --> Caused by: org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.internal.InstantiationException: Unable to determine dynamic instantiation injection strategy for org.kisanag.model.mandi.MarketCommodityInfo#commodityInfo. I feel blessed to hear from you directly.

Comment: When you specify `as` in this context, you're asking for field/setter injection, not constructor injection.

Comment: Thanks Gavin. Can you point me to documentation which can help me use constructor injection. Searched through google without an luck.

Comment: I'm not sure where it's documented (if at all) but you can see exactly how it works by checking the code from line 148 onward in `DynamicInstantiationResultImpl`.

Comment: Thanks adding FunctionContributor resolved my issue. Will take a look at the code for constructor instantiation.